# How do I speed up the Maven clean install? Taking 2 hours to complete

Tags: maven-3, isis

Im currently having a problem that I believe is Maven. For an university project, we are requiered to use intelliJ IDEA, java SDK, Apache Maven and Isis. I tried to follow the tutorial for Isis, creating a project, paste the arquetype on the terminal to build it and the mvn clean install, just as I do that, its starts downloading the dependencies but reallyyy slow, Im taking about 2 hours downloading and still doing it, the other students can install it in 3 minutes, so something is definitely wrong. Any suggestions?

Try it on Ubuntu, Fedora, and Windows. No improvement, other archetypes are created fine. Try "mvn -T 1C clean install -Dmaven.test.skip -DskipTests" to skip test when building the project, no improvement. Try it on other notebook and same result! I went through the guide and setup of maven and isis and I dont see if Im doing something wrong.

I expect to uses Isis simpleApp archetype and build succesfully the project with maven under 5 minutes instead of 2 hours.

Comment: Have you defined version for the dependencies you are using ?

Comment: I just followed the simpleApp archetype steps on the isis page , so I believe I have not, can you explain how to do that, please?

Comment: check your pom file

Answer (score 1):

Slowness for downloading maven dependencies is dependent on following factors:

- Servers hosting repositories, where dependencies are present, are not
  responding fast.
- Low Internet speed although it is less likely.

On another note, For any maven module when, very first time, it is compiled, it would definitely take time as it will download all the dependencies which are not present in local .m2 folder.

One temporary solution is to copy .m2 folder from another student's machine.